# Make LiveServerTestCase not to call setUp() before each test

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-1.4, factory-boy

I have one problem with testing django app by using LiveServerTestCase. LiveServerTestCase execute setUp() function before executing each test. But I'm using factory-boy's factories to create objects for testing (users, items, etc...). And the same objects are created before executing each test. How can I create this objects one time and make all tests to see this objects in database?

Answer (score 1):

`setUp()` gets called before every test.

If you want to create the objects once for the entrire test case, you can use `setUpClass()` instead.

E.g.

```
class SomeTest(LiveServerTestCase):
        @classmethod
        def setUpClass(cls):
            # create objects here
            LiveServerTestCase.setUpClass()
```

Don't forget to call `LiveServerTestCase.setUpClass()` or the live server won't function properly.