# Django LiveServerTestCase: User created in in setUpClass method not available in test_method?

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-testing

I am using Django 1.4's LiveServerTestCase for Selenium testing and am having trouble with the `setUpClass` class method. As far as I understand `MembershipTests.setUpClass` is run once before the unit tests are run.

I've put code to add a user to the database in `MembershipTests.setUpClass` but when I run the `MembershipTests.test_signup` test no user has been added to the test database. ***What am I doing incorrectly?*** I expect the user I created in `setUpClass` would be available across all unit tests.

If I put the user creation code in `MembershipTests.setUp` and run `MembershipTests.test_signup` I can see the user, but don't want this run before every unit test as `setUp` is. As you can see, I use a custom LiveServerTestCase class to add basic functionality across all of my tests (`test_utils.CustomLiveTestCase`). I suspect this has something to do with my issue.

Thanks in advance.

**test_utils.py**:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase

class CustomLiveTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.wd = WebDriver()
        super(CustomLiveTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.wd.quit()
        super(CustomLiveTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()
```

**tests.py**:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test.utils import override_settings
from test_utils import CustomLiveTestCase 
from test_constants import *

@override_settings(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY='xxx', STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY='xxx')
class MembershipTests(CustomLiveTestCase):

    fixtures = [
        'account_extras/fixtures/test_socialapp_data.json',
        'membership/fixtures/basic/plan.json',
    ]

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super(MembershipTests, cls).setUpClass()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            TEST_USER_USERNAME,
            TEST_USER_EMAIL,
            TEST_USER_PASSWORD
        )

    def test_signup(self):
        print "users: ", User.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you're using LiveServerTestCase it's almost same as TransactionTestCase which creates and destroys database (truncates tables) for every testcase ran.

So you really can't do global data with LiveServerTestCase.

Comment: Any ideas, how could I create a user and then log it in, with LiveServerTestCase? Creating the account in setUp with SQLite database in :memory: does not work, even if I commit manually.

Answer (score 17):

The database is torn down and reloaded on every test method, not on the test class. So your user will be lost each time. Do that in `setUp` not `setUpClass`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Does that mean that [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14038336/378638) is incorrect or am I misunderstanding it? Is it just not possible to create test records in one place for use across all test methods in a test class? I want to use the same user record across all test methods and ``setUp`` ends up recreating it before each one.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use `TestCase.setUpTestData` as follows (slight changes to your base class):

**test_utils.py**:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase, TestCase

class CustomLiveTestCase(LiveServerTestCase, TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.wd = WebDriver()
        super(CustomLiveTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.wd.quit()
        super(CustomLiveTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()
```

**tests.py**:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test.utils import override_settings
from test_utils import CustomLiveTestCase
from test_constants import *

@override_settings(STRIPE_SECRET_KEY='xxx', STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY='xxx')
class MembershipTests(CustomLiveTestCase):

    fixtures = [
        'account_extras/fixtures/test_socialapp_data.json',
        'membership/fixtures/basic/plan.json',
    ]

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        super(MembershipTests, cls).setUpTestData()
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            TEST_USER_USERNAME,
            TEST_USER_EMAIL,
            TEST_USER_PASSWORD
        )

    def test_signup(self):
        print "users: ", User.objects.all()
```

Instead of changing the base class, you could inherit from `TestCase` in MembershipTests, but you'll have to do this everytime you need test data.

Note that I've also removed the `def setUp: pass`, as this will break the transaction handling.

Check out this thread for further details: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/sr3gnsc8gig

Let me know if you run into any issues with this solution!

Comment: setUpTestData is the ideal way to go for creating objects once per class.

Comment: I tried this, but the data did not appear in the browser - however it was accessible in model queries. Could the selenium server be accessing a db different to the one model classes are using?!

Comment: @cammil Yes,  unfortunately a bit more complicated than I presented here. I'll update my answer when I get a moment, but tldr the live server test case spawns a different process to communicate with the browser and so can't see into your transaction.  Switch in TransactionTestCase for test case is the high level fix,  but then there are complications with managing the data.   My plan (if I ever get to it) is to write a new db driver that runs in a separate process and shares transactions, but it's a bit of work.

Comment: Alternatively, if your db supports UNCOMMITTED READ isolation level,  use that and save yourself substantial headache.

Comment: @DylanYoung Based on this article http://atodorov.org/blog/2017/12/26/on-pytest-django-and-liveservertestcase-with-initial-data/ I am overriding `self._fixture_setup` to create data. And so far, it seems to be working. Is this the least of all evils, in your opinion?